# Simplifying MySQL query union

Tags: mysql, database, union, simplify

I need to know, is this the right way to do this:

```
(SELECT id, name, 1 AS reference FROM antenna WHERE id IN (SELECT antenna_id FROM reference)) 
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT id, name, 0 AS reference FROM antenna WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT antenna_id FROM reference))
```

Have been doing it for some time and even though it works perfectly, it is quite ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I am not sure it works, test and benchmark:

```
SELECT antenna.id, antenna.name, CASE WHEN COALESCE(reference.antenna_id, 0)!=0 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS reference FROM antenna LEFT JOIN reference 
ON antenna.id=reference.antenna_id
```

Comment: This works! Wasn't avare of COALESCE clause. Now it is quite hard to read for me, but thanks!

Comment: @delmadord what is it you cannot read? This should be faster than your query, but you still have to try.

Comment: I mean harder to understand as I read. Do not get me wrong, this is certainly an opportunity to improve my knowledge, not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will work.
But IN clause gives poor performance as compare to JOIN. Also, IN clause has limit of 1000 records.

Use this query instead-

```
(SELECT id, name, 1 AS reference FROM antenna a, reference ref
where a.id = ref.antenna_id)
UNION
(SELECT id, name, 0 AS reference FROM antenna a, reference ref
where a.id != ref.antenna_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, however it does show every column of antenna with reference as 0 and then every column of reference with 1, so not the expected result. However, your notes were helpful and informative.